# Redirect routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have an old wordpress woocommerce site that I rebuilt in rails.

Obviously it has a Product model and Products controller with routes.

The site is ready to launch.

My only problem is the old links go

```
www.mydomain.com/product/product-name
```

how do I either redirect or change my

```
www.mydomain.com/products/product-name
```

my routes file looks like so

```
resources :products do
    resource :like, only: [:create,:destroy], module: :products
    resource :collect, only: [:create,:destroy], module: :products do
      put :sort, on: :collection
    end
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

get '/product/:name', to: redirect('/products/%{name}')

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it offers a great way to ensure all my backlinks remain working and I can improve the logic with the new app.

Answer (score 1):

you may check [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) check section 4.7 Translated Paths

for your case above the translated route

```
resources :products, path: 'product'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this answer, I love the simplicity of rails and the documentation